# "HelloWorld" program on MIPS is not working when loaded by linux core to another core

Tags: ld, elf, mips32

A program "HelloWorld" running on Mips Interaptive core0 VPE1, including crt0.S (which I wrote), main.c files creates an ELF in which the symbols are relative to 0x0:
0x0 - _core_reset (this is part of crt0.S)
...
0x460 - fw_reset (this is called from main)
...
0x484 - main (this is the main function)

(-) my ELF undergoes stripping of sections to create a binary file of instructions only, starting in _core_reset
(-) the binary image from last step is loaded to virtual address 0xADB00000, which is physical 0x2DB00000
(-) the first problem is that in _core_reset we do:

```
la t0,main
```

mtc0 t0,C0_ERRPC //store it as return address
but main has the address relative to 0x0, which causes memory exception,
what I need is main to be in address loaded + (offset relative to zero),
How do I do that? we can say that the address the image is loaded to and run from is constant

1. I tried to write in the crt0.S file, hardcoded to change the jump to main address:

   lui t0, 0xa6b0 /* Assumtion the FW is loaded to 0xa6b00000 */
     addiu t0, t0, main

and it worked an I reached main(), but later when tried to call fw_reset() from main, the address of fw_reset() was again relative to 0x0 and I got a memory exception

2. I tried from the makefile to add that the .text section of ELF will start from the address loaded, but then I get an issue that my image is loaded to:
   (value i provide) + (actual loading address) and so it also doesn't work

I expected my code to reach main() and be stuck in the endless while loop, instead I get memory exceptions since the functions are relative to 0x0, while the code is loaded to another address not zero